# org-mode conditional dir property

Tags: org-mode, directories

In org-mode, you are able to set the directory property for a heading in a straightforward manner by placing the following text under your heading of choice:

```
:PROPERTIES:
:DIR: ~/path/to/my_folder/
:END:
```

I frequently switch back and forth between a mac and a PC and the pathname to a particular directory might change slightly between the two platforms (e.g., `~/path/to/my_folder` in my mac and `c://users/me/path/to/my_folder` in my PC.)

In lieu of changing my home variable, is there a way to make a heading-specific property conditional in org-mode? Or is there a way to set the dir property of a specific heading to a variable that I define in my init file?

Comment: How about using something like `(concat my-variable "/path/to/my_folder")` where `my-variable` is programmatically determined based upon the platform?  How / when the programmatic determination is made depends upon the use-case.  A common usage of such a variable can be seen with `user-emacs-directory` ...

Comment: What happens if you use (expand-file-name "~/path/to/my_folder") on windows and mac, do they expand to the right result? If so, always use ~/path and then expand it in your code.

Comment: I have several pathname variables that I use for functions defined in my init file, which use expand-file-name and they work great. So, I guess my question is how can I execute those variables in the properties drawer of a heading? For example, if I do the following `(setq example-folder "c://users/me/Desktop/")` and then set the DIR property in an org-mode heading to the variable `example-folder`, emacs points to a directory "example-folder" in my current buffer's directory and not to the pathname stored in that variable. Is there a way to execute elisp in the heading properties drawer?

Comment: "Is there a way to execute elisp in the heading properties drawer?" The answer is "no" to this (well, there's probably various tricks that you could do -- e.g. preprocess the files when first opened by using a hook -- but they would be complicated and fragile IMO).

Comment: Bummer. I was thinking since you can execute elisp in header arguments in source code blocks, you might be able to do something similar with heading property args in org-mode. Hmmmmmmmmmm... Ok, so then my next thought would be to ask if it's possible to set the DIR property of specific org-mode headings in my init file on start-up? But I'm guessing I might be able to apropos this in emacs.